# WebSocket connection: can it follow a previous HTTP/1.1 request/response?

Tags: http, websocket

Can a WebSocket connection be initiated using a TCP (or TCP+TLS) connection already used by one or more regular HTTP request/responses, or does the client have to initiate a new TCP connection for each WebSocket connection?

[Asking in the context of extending an HTTP client to support also making WebSockets connections. The client maintains a pool of keep-alive connections, and wondering if when making a WebSocket connection, if it can use a TCP connection from the pool.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.1

> Once a connection to the server has been established (including a connection via a proxy or over a TLS-encrypted tunnel), the client MUST send an opening handshake to the server.

The language suggests to me that there shouldn't be anything [e.g. an HTTP request/response] between opening the connection and sending the WebSocket opening handshake would not adhere to the spec.

So no, connections alive from previous HTTP request/responses cannot be used for WebSockets.